# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'type_article_id' in 'field list'- laravel8_livewire (SQL: insert into `voitures` (`no`, `noSe

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new here and I using the framework laravel with livewire
I've 2 tables(voitures and type_voiture).When I want to execute php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
I get the error message:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'type_article_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `voitures` (`nom`, `noSerie`, `imageUrl`, `type_article_id`, `estDisponible`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Will, MMXFRQQC, images/imageplaceholder.png, 1, 1, 2022-08-02 11:06:33, 2022-08-02 11:06:33))

Migration Voitures
Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}

```
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table("voitures", function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->dropForeign("type_voiture_id");
    });
    Schema::dropIfExists('voitures');
}
```

}

class CreateTypeVoitureTable extends Migration
{
/**
* Run the migrations.
*
* @return void
*/
public function up()
{
Schema::create('type_voiture', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->id();
$table->string("nom")->unique();
$table->timestamps();
});
}

```
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('type_voiture');
}
```

}

Seeders TypeVoiture
class TypeVoitureTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
* Run the database seeds.
*
* @return void
*/
public function run()
{
DB::table("type_voiture")->insert([
["nom"=> "VoitureDeLuxe"],
["nom"=> "pick-up"],
["nom"=> "hybrides"],
["nom"=> "Limousines"]
]);

```
    DB::table("propriete_voitures")->insert([
        ["nom" => "Marque", "type_voiture_id" => 1],
        ["nom" => "Kilometrage", "type_voiture_id" => 1],
        ["nom" => "Prix", "type_voiture_id" => 2],
        ["nom" => "Libelle", "type_voiture_id" => 2],
        ["nom" => "Marque", "type_voiture_id" => 3],
    ]);
```

the migration to the database was successful:

Migrating: 2021_06_22_044045_create_type_voiture_table
Migrated:  2021_06_22_044045_create_type_voiture_table (584.08ms)
Migrating: 2021_06_22_044047_create_voitures_table
Migrated:  2021_06_22_044047_create_voitures_table (2,039.55ms)

I changed the name "article" to "voiture" and then "type_article" to "Type_voiture"
And now that I want to create seeders it doesn't work. please what did i do wrong

Comment: can you add the migration where you create the tables?

Comment: The query you provided isn't the one that is running.  It is trying to insert into the voiture table.  `insert into **voitures**`

Comment: please What should I put instead

Answer (score 0):

```
class CreateTypeVoitureTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('type_voiture', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("nom")->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('type_voiture');
    }
}
```